# How can I part ofJSON-Array shown?

Tags: arrays, object, typescript

How can I only show this part

**/db/User_DataDb/61500546-4e63-42fd-9d54-b92d0f7b9be1** of this entire

*Object obj.sel_an:*

```
[
    {
        "__zone_symbol__state":true,
        "__zone_symbol__value":"/db/User_DataDb/61500546-4e63-42fd-9d54-b92d0f7b9be1"
    }
]
```

I wrote

```
console.log("obj.sel_an: ",
JSON.stringify(this.sel_and.__zone_symbol__value))
```

And the console displays this error: ‘***obj.sel_an:  undefined.***’

[image]

Comment: `this.sel_and[0].__zone_symbol__value`

Comment: @dbandstra 
Hello, thanks, it’s working. It's working if I know the exact index of the object.
If an object has more information and is located in a database collection, I want to copy that information and save it in another database collection. Then I want to have the saved data of both collections shown at once with Angular2.
Do you maybe know how I can do that? 
I attempted to save this object into the database as Set() and Array() and show it in html. 
But it isn’t working. Or should I just try to ask the forum?

Comment: Use `for` loop or forEach function which is available on `this.sel_and` obejct. For example: `this.sel_and.forEach(function (child) { console.log(child.__zone_symbol__value) });`

Comment: @Misaz, hello and thanks. I'll answer you with another comment.

Answer (score 0):

> @Misaz here is my answer I talked about in the last comment.
>
> Here is a section or rather a part of my code
>
> ```
> db.Coll1.find()
>          .equal('id', and.id)
> .resultList(result => {
>                 result.forEach(db1 => {
>                   if (db1.sel_and === null) {
>                      db1.sel_and = new Set();                                                                
>                 }
>
>                if (db1.sel_an === null) {
>                     db1.sel_an = new Array();
>                }
>
>
>  db1.sel_an.push(promise1); // here is a JsonArray 
>  db1.sel_and.add(promise1);  // here is a Set()
>
>
>
>    var db_child: any;
>    db_child = db1.sel_and.forEach(function (child) {console.log(child[0].__zone_symbol__value) });
>    console.log(" db1.sel_and: ", db_child);
>     return db1.update({ refresh: true });
>     });
> ```
>
> Here is the result by JsonArray
>
> 1. By db1.sel_an.push(promise1);
>      save in collection
>
>    [
>        {
>          "__zone_symbol__state": true,
>          "__zone_symbol__value": "/db/User_DataDb/f6fe3fe3-17f1-49d8-83c3-b36dda42026d"
>        }
>      ]
>
> Console output:
>
> ```
> ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}
>   __zone_symbol__state:true
>   __zone_symbol__value:"/db/User_DataDb/d79ef084-17fc-441c-a8eb-13ba0a14f083"
>   __proto__:Object
> ```

2. Here is the result of the Set()

-> “***db1.sel_and.add(promise1)***;”  -> is saved as ***[null]*** in the Collection, but it should be saved as 
-> **["/db/User_DataDb/f55bf96d-2cb9-467f-8aa8-d60aced32fcf"]**

> ```
> Set(1) {ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: true, __zone_symbol__value: "/db/User_DataDb/f55bf96d-2cb9-467f-8aa8-d60aced32fcf"}}
>   size:(...)
>   __persistedSize__:1
>   __persistedState__:Object
>   __proto__:Set
>   [[Entries]]:Array(1)
>   0:null
>   length:1
>
> 3.    
>
> db_child = db1.sel_and.forEach(function (child) { console.log(child[0].__zone_symbol__value) });
>      console.log(" db1.sel_and: ", db_child);
> ```
>
> I tried it with  child[0].__zone_symbol__value But I got errors:
>
> ```
> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '__zone_symbol__value' of undefined
> TypeError: Cannot read property '__zone_symbol__value' of undefined
>     at http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:28348:116
>     at Set.forEach (native)
>     at http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:28348:69
>     at Array.forEach (native)
>     at http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:28336:44
>     at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4341:26)
>     at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:30326:37)
>     at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4340:32)
>     at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4133:43)
>     at http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4720:57
>     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4374:31)
>     at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:30317:37)
>     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4373:36)
>     at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4173:47)
>     at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4553:35) 
>     at ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4431:25)
> ```
>
> If I don’t write [0] at the end of child, I get “undefined”.If I written child.__zone_symbol__value, I get wrong . How can I
>   leave out the “[0].__zone_symbol__value” without getting an error? Is
>   it possible at all?

Thanks